# Inserting tags into the <head> section using GTM

Tags: javascript, tags

Is it possible to insert script into the `<head>` section using GTM (Google Tag Manager)?

I'm thinking, yes it probably is, using JS - but I guess the tags may not function properly if this is the case.

What about if we put the GTM container into the header, but hard code the `<noscript>` section in the `<body>` instead?

Comment: Why not try it out and report back here?? :D Turn that "probably is" into a "definitely can" or "definitely can't".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can successfully do it in the sense that the JS fires and it places the tag into the header. I'm just curious what the accepted convention is here and the reasons one would insert a tag into the head section. For example, presumably the purpose of putting, say, a third party tracking tag in the head is that it fires as early as possible..